# Value of $\lim _{t\to 0^+}\left(\frac{1}{\pi t^2}\iint f\left(x,y\right)dxdy\:\right)$, D=$\{(x,y)|x^2+y^2 \le t^2\}$

Tags: calculus

> $$
> I=\lim _{t\to 0^+}\left(\frac{1}{\pi t^2}\iint f\left(x,y\right)dxdy\:\right),\quad
> D=\{(x,y)|x^2+y^2 \le t^2\}
> $$

**I know this question can use the fact that**

$$
\:\iint f\left(x,y\right)d\sigma \:=f\left(\zeta ,\eta \right)\cdot \pi t^2.
$$

**But is this another right solution (or how to understand this solution)?**

> $$
> \begin{split}
> I &=\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{1}{\pi t^2}\int\limits_0^{2\pi }d\theta \int \limits_0^tf\left(r\cos\theta ,r\sin\theta \right)rdr\\
> & =\lim_{t\to \:0^+} \frac{2}{t^2}\int\limits_0^{t} f(r\cos\theta ',r\sin\theta')rdr
> \end{split}
> \theta '\in \left[0,2\pi \right]
> $$

Comment: @peek-a-boo That's what I thought, but did you notice that the $\theta $ here changed to $\theta'$?

Comment: my bad I hadn't noticed that

Comment: what do σ,ζ,η stand for?

Comment: @YotamMaozY The first problem was solved using the integral mean value theorem.